# var cl = console.log doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I did this in my Angular app:

```
var cl = console.log;
cl(123);
```

however, I had the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

This happened in Chrome. It works in Nodejs.

I'm confused. Is it illegal code?

Comment: Try `var cl = console.log.bind(console)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Amply explained in the linked question.

Comment: There are many duplicates. Long story short, `console.log`'s implementation depends on the context method is run in. It means that `this` inside needs to be `console` object and nothing else. Hence, you should only run `console.log` method in context of the `console` object. What happens when you assign `var log = console.log` is that you detach function from the origin and it just looses context.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen: You're calling it with the wrong `this`. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L48-L53

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cl` only references the `log()` method. `log()` expects `console` as context but gets `window`. To solve, bind `console` as context:

```js
var cl = console.log.bind(console);
cl("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Thanks. Now I got the idea why. :)